# How do I use Dynamic Fields in aslagle/reactive-table

Tags: meteor

Does anyone have more details on how to use Dynamic Fields in  aslagle/reactive-table (I find the [documentation](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#dynamic-columns) confusing.

I'm trying to add a column with a check box, such that as a person clicks on a row, the check box is toggled.

This way a user can page through a table of records and select items, then when they are done selecting I'll save their final choices.

Right now I can only capture click events by row.  But I cannot figure out how to save clicks from as a person moves from one page to another.

Here's how I create the checkbox, using a columncell template; I'm using a unique record id (i.e. 'rin') as a html element id.

```
<template name="checkboxCellData">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{ rin }}" checked="{{ clicked }}">
</template>
```

Heres the event toggle.

```
Template.regsUnderReview.events({
  'click #reactive-table-1 tbody tr': function (event) {
    // When the row is clicked get that rows data
    var row = this;
    let cb = document.getElementById(row.rin);
    if (row.clicked) { 
      row.clicked=false;
      //set check box when row is clikked   
      cb.checked = false; 
    } else { 
      row.clicked = true;
      cb.checked=true;
    }
  }
});
```

I think I'm only saving the checkbook state in the DOM, and not the correct Reactive table location....I don't want to store the value in the database, because I'll have tons of users saving their selections...I'll only want cache their selections in the web browser and then on final seletion, save the IDs selected to a user settings database.

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor sessions](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) may be what you're looking for.

You can initiate one with `Session.set("yourKey", "yourValue")`, and you can get the data by using `Session.get("yourKey")`. Sessions in Meteor are also reactive.

If you are using Meteor 1.3+, you will probably have to add the session package with `meteor add session` in order to use the above methods.

Comment: I'll look into sessions. But I don't think it fully solves the issue. In the reactive table, when you page forward, I'll have to loop through that pages displayed rows to see if any have been saved into Session and display it checked (or not)....but I don't think this will allow me to use reactive tables builtit sort. to sort the entire table ( such that when you click on a column it sorts clicked/saved rows on top)

Comment: Well, I think what you want to do is manipulate the table state as described [here](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#accessing-and-controlling-table-state). This link has an example of how to use `Session` and `reactiveVar`. Also, reading up on [reactiveVar](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) would probably be useful as that may be the way you actually want to go.

Comment: Thanks. I'm moving in the direction of using a userSettings collection.  Then on row click, saving the user's row selection; when table is draw, I'm updating status.  .... I'm now trying to figure out how to to prevent clicking on the checkbox (which is part of a row) from also triggering the clickrow event...which cause the checkbox to be checked then immediately unchecked.  The behavior works properly when clicking any other part of the row.

Comment: That might be a simpler solution. You could also set up a [local collection](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#local-collections), which is a client side only collection, for data storage during a session, and then drop the collection when the session ends or save it and let the user options persist. To do this, you would just do `userSettings = new Mongo.Collection(null);` on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.